# Unable to display html entity &#1235 into notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm unable to display html entity character &#1235 into notepad++ v6.2.3

I took the output of html entity &#1235 character, which displays correctly from the web browser, and it displays as a square box and not character of html entity &#1235 but all other characters display correctly into notepad++

The notepad++ file is saved as unicode UTF8

Comment: Maybe your font doesn't have that symbol?

Comment: what font do I need for this support?

Comment: I found out Arial support this unicode type. thanks gronstaj leading me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I get that character as ӓ, and it shows up correctly in notepad++ for me. It works with Courier New and Consolas. Try a different console font and it should work.